# Вопрос об исxоде футбольного матча

Tags: фразеология

Как правильно задать вопрос об исxоде футбольного матча: кто победит, как завершится, чем завершится?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Чаще используются два вопроса: кто победит и как завершится матч, так как вариантов здесь немного: победа, поражение, ничья.

Выражение "чем завершится" больше подходит для тех случаев, когда варианты могут быть разные, в том числе когда их трудно вообще предвидеть, например:

Когда я начинал эти заметки, я еще не знал, чем завершится вся история.

Answer (score 1):

Все варианты правильные и не имеют существенной стилистической разницы. впрочем, если ну очень сильно придираться, то "Кто победит?" предполагает, что ничьей не будет.

Других поводов ломать копья не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - как завершится матч.

> Кто победит в матче?

Не совсем правильно, потому что в футболе бывают ничьи.

> Чем завершится матч?

Все футбольные матчи завершаются финальным свистком.

Comment: На чем ваше мнение построено?

Comment: Все футбольные матчи завершаются финальным свистком, но вместе с тем некоторые завершаются победой одной из команд, другие - ничьей. Почему Вы считаете, что правильно писать "как"?